# Displaying name initials instead of profile picture

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, frontend

I am trying to implement a profile picture option in a React JS frontend similar to what Google Plus/Gmail does. If there is no profile picture available then the first letters of the words in the name are extracted and dispalyed instead of a profile picture.

I have made the appropriate div and the CSS for displaying and the initials are getting extracted as well but aren't displayed.
[This image is a good example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5a8Cf.png)

HTML:

```
<li className="nav-item">

                   <div id="container_acronym">
                     <div id="name_acronym">                        
                        {this.acronym_name(this.state.lead_details.customer_name)}
                     </div>
                    </div>                 
            </li>
```

CSS:

```
    #container_acronym {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #333;
  }
  #name_acronym {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 100px;
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
acronym_name(str){
    var regular_ex=/\b(\w)/g;
    var matches = str.match(regular_ex);
    var acronym = matches.join('');
    document.getElementById("name_acronym").innerHTML = acronym;
}
```

Comment: Also I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined"  error.

Comment: Your `this.state.lead_details.customer_name` must be `undefined` for that to happen. [Check out conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

Comment: Correct. It is undefined in <div id="name_acronym"> as I found that out by adding a comsole.log() there. I don't understand why it is so.

Comment: You should render that part only when you successfully retrieve lead_details from your data source.

Comment: It is retrieved outside this code block. I tried replacing the above  HTML with console.log(this.state.lead_details.customer_name) and the name is rendered in the console.

Comment: Why is it undefined?

Comment: You should provide more information on that problem. Try opening a new question.

Comment: Done [Here is the link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175265/cannot-read-property-match-of-undefined-error/49190482#49190482)

Answer (score 1):

you need to return the name from `acronym_name(str)` function instead of setting `innerHTML`, like:

```
...
acronym_name(str){
    var regular_ex=/\b(\w)/g;
    var matches = str.match(regular_ex);
    var acronym = matches.join('');
    //return the acronym
    return acronym;
}
```

Comment: When I debugged my code, both `innerHTML` and `return acronym` did the same thing. I have added link to working code in the comments above.